# Manage Ubuntu Cloud with C#

Tags: c#, ubuntu, cloud

I would like to know if it's possible to manage my cloud using either Eucalyptus's APIs or OpenStacks APIs using C#.

I've been looking on ways to do it and I don't think it's possible, even using MonoDevelop.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think it possible but this question deserves to be followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Eucalyptus and OpenStack APIs are REST based. The Ubuntu Cloud is based on OpenStack (last I checked!) and should expose accessible REST APIs. You should then be able to use something like [this opensource library](https://github.com/rackspace/openstack.net) to manage the Ubuntu Cloud that you set up.

It's been a while since I have touched an Ubuntu Cloud (too much work) and have since been using Amazon EC2. I setup a simple Ubuntu Cloud and for a little bit wrote Python application to control the creation of VMs via OpenStacks REST API.

I hope this helps you!